# Change link with jQuery depending on class

Tags: jquery, css, class, hyperlink

Is there a way to change the link text on the fly with jQuery, if the link class changes?

Initial state (no class):

```
<a href="#" class="">Save This</a>
```

If above is clicked it is given a class as below:

```
<a href="#" class="saved">Save This</a>
```

I would like to end up with this:

```
<a href="#" class="saved">Remove This</a>
```

What I would like if is the class changes to "saved", I want to change the initial text 'Save This' to 'Remove This'.

Comment: you need to do that when you are adding the class saved.

Comment: See my answer for your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/a6vjxy6c/2/

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass("saved")) {
     $(this).removeClass("saved");
        $(this).html("Save This");
    }
    else {
     $(this).addClass("saved");
        $(this).html("Remove This");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('saved');
    $(this).text('Remove This');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rwpfgx5d/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8573njtu/)

Assigning `id` will provide unique operation

HTML:

```
<a id="btn" href="#" class="">Save This</a>
```

SCRIPT:

```
 $("#btn").click(function () {
            $(this).addClass("saved");
            $(this).html("Remove This");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hasClass('saved')?$(this).html('Remove This'):$(this).addClass('saved');
    });
```